# invalid partition table?

Tags: 14.04, windows, system-installation, partitioning

I'm trying to install `ubuntu` by `usb device`, I've extracted the iso ubuntu image to a flash disk then I booted from the usb device but it keeps showing me this message `"invalid partition table"`, so can anyone helps me here please ?

Comment: Are you trying to install a dual boot system?

Comment: yes, I've already windows 7 and I want to install ubuntu too beside it.

Comment: "invalid partition table" is actually an error from Windows, you will probably need to use Windows to fix it, see answer here: [Fixing bad Windows partition](http://superuser.com/questions/300906/fixing-bad-windows-partition-and-startup-with-linux), for `bootrec` commands see [Hard time installing Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/184940/hard-time-installing-ubuntu)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tried to edit partitions now it says "Invalid partition table"](http://askubuntu.com/questions/432939/tried-to-edit-partitions-now-it-says-invalid-partition-table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you extraction of ISO to USB went wrong. Do it again, with different application. Ubuntu CD ISO images are not CD images, but hybrid images. If you write them to USB stick as CD images, you get crap. All you need is a one-to-one copy of ISO on USB, no loaders, no syslinuxes, nothing else. 
On linux one would use dd to do it

```
dd if=[ubuntu.iso] of=/dev/[sda-z] bs=4M
```

Comment: Before running this, do make sure that `/dev/sda` is the USB key and not the hard drive. You may overwrite your hard drive if you do not check this properly.